# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1, java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I want to get json objects from a webservice and display them in a list view,

this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JsonObject data = null;
    private JsonObject response = null;
    private JsonArray records = null;
    private JsonObject record = null;
    private ArrayList<SearchResults> results = null;
    SearchResults sr1 = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults() {
        results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();       
        new GetResults().execute("");

        return results;
    }

    private class GetResults extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Map<String, String> callArgs = new HashMap<String, String>(1);

            callArgs.put("suuid", "dtr0bdQGcqwSh3QO7fVwgVfBNWog6mvEbAyljlLX9E642Yfmur");

            try {
                response = EventPulseCloud.call("ListEvents", callArgs);
            } catch (HttpClientException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response.get("Type").toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(result.equals("success")) {

                data = (JsonObject) response.get("Data");
                records = (JsonArray) data.get("Records");

                try {
                    records = response.getObject ("Data").getArray ("Records");
                } catch (JsonException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < records.count(); i ++) {
                    record = (JsonObject) records.get(i);

                    sr1 = new SearchResults();
                    sr1.setAddress(record.get("address").toString());
                    sr1.setStartingDate(record.get("StartingDate").toString());
                    sr1.setTicketCategories(record.get("ticketCategories").toString());
                results.add(sr1);

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

> and I get this in the logcat :

```
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at com.example.listview.MainActivity$GetResults.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:73)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at com.example.listview.MainActivity$GetResults.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-05 15:53:39.765: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):    ... 5 more
06-05 15:53:40.050: I/Process(10012): Sending signal. PID: 10012 SIG: 9
```

In the logcat, the line : **MainActivity.java:73** is :

```
return response.get("Type").toString();
```

Everything seems correct to me... Please, do you have any idea about this ? Thank you :)

**EDIT :** 
when I try this code in java :

```
Map<String, String> callArgs = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
    callArgs.put("suuid", "dtr0bdQGcqwSh3QO7fVwgVfBNWog6mvEbAyljlLX9E642Yfmur");
    response = EventPulseCloud.call("ListEvents", callArgs);

    if(response.get("Type").equals("success")) {
         JsonArray records = response.getObject ("Data").getArray ("Records");
         for (int i = 0; i < records.count (); i++) {
              JsonObject record = (JsonObject)records.get (i);
              System.out.print(record.get("ticketCategories").toString());
         }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No");
```

and it displays on screen :

["SingleDay"]
["SingleDay"]
["Regular Ticket"]

it does mean that it returns something.

Comment: `response` is `null` so this line `response = EventPulseCloud.call("ListEvents", callArgs);` is probably returning `null`. I would check if that is the case

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the result of `response.get("Type")` is null.  You should really check the return of that before trying to do something with it.

Comment: `response` itself is `null` or the exception would be in `onPostExecute()`, I believe

Comment: Thank you :) I have added a specification in the question can you check my edit please ?

Answer (score 1):

`response.get("Type")` is returning null. Make sure you are are looking for the correct thing (maybe it's "type" instead of "Type"?) and, if nothing else, add some null-checking.

```
Object typeObj = response.get("Type");
if (typeObj != null) {
    return typeObj.toString();
}
return null;
```

Comment: `response` could also be null.

Comment: Without knowing what web services you are calling or what the response should look like, the only discernable thing to any of us here is that you have a NullPointerException, which happens when you try to access a member variable or call a method on an object that is not initialized. The rest is up to you to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, It was a little problem I've solved it and it works now but I got another problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948937/skipped-60-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread
can you check it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the request for permission to access internet is missing. to avoid it. In Android Manifest file add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```