# A lot of setText and String assignment

Tags: android, string, multithreading, settext, massive

I have a lot of getting String from json objects like this:

```
city1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("object").getJSONObject(0).getString("city");
```

And if value not hull i apply this String to textview:

```
if(city1.equals("")) {
   citylayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
prefsmain2.edit().putInt("CITY", city1).commit();
citytxt.setText(city1);
}
```

I have ~60 parametrs like this (city, landmark, region, country etc...)
But i get a log from debugger:

> Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

Get values from AsyncTask and work with setText on new thread using Handler, but its useless...

Comment: check whether you are fetching `JSON` in `asyncTask` ? ... if you are using  `Asynctask` update your `textview` in `onpostexecute` !

Comment: Ironz, your question is answered in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948937/skipped-60-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom view which acts like multiple textviews.Give data to it all at once and invalidate the view.Using this approach u might avoid many redraws which might be causing frame drops.